# How do I set the base URL for jquery's links when transitioning between html pages

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have two pages, index.html and testpage.html

testpage.html consists of two page elements foo and bar with links between them.

I transition to testpage.html from index.html with an ajax call. The problem is that the links on testpage.html are using the index.html as the base url. So when I try to go from #foo to #bar I catch a pagechangefail

```
 $( document ).bind( "pagechangefailed", function( event, data ){
            alert('failed change ' + data.toPage);

        });
```

This alerts "failed change http://domain.com/mobile/index.html#bar"

The problem is obviously that #bar doesn't exist on index.html but does exist on testpage.html. I don't get why the link is trying to link back to the original page. How can I manually set the link or try to manually override somehow? I tried something like

```
$.mobile.changePage('testpage.html#bar');
```

but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think jQM Sees this as 'Deep Linking' but I see that's not what you're trying to accomplish

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html

> **PLEASE NOTE**: Since we are using the hash to track navigation history for all the Ajax 'pages', it's not currently possible to deep
>   link to an anchor `(index.html#foo)` on a page in jQuery Mobile,
>   because the framework will look for a 'page' with an ID of `#foo`
>   instead of the native behavior of scrolling to the content with that
>   ID.

I think (But have not tried this) you need to use `$.mobile.loadPage('testpage.html')` to load the page into the DOM first, then use `$.mobile.changePage('#bar')` to transition.

More on that here:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/api/methods.html

Also I've seen use of the ***target attribute*** but not sure if this would work using `$.mobile.changePage()`

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/pages/page-links.html